# Laravel 5.7 Account Varification Email gives "Illegal offset type" Exception

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5.7

I implemented Laravel's Authentication. Everything is working fine except account verification. When I `Signup/Regiser` I receive `Account Verification` email with a `verification link`. When I click on provided link to verify my account I got following `Exception`

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Illegal offset type
/var/www/html/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php

public function __construct($app)
{
    $this->app = $app;

    $this->userResolver = function ($guard = null) {
        return $this->guard($guard)->user();
    };
}

/**
 * Attempt to get the guard from the local cache.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
public function guard($name = null)
{
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

    return $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);
}
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP 7.2

Comment: What's the line number ?

Comment: Pointing following line:
return $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);

Comment: On `AuthManager.php` its line number **68**

Comment: I strongly think your server doesn't use PHP 7.2 but 5.6. `??` is a >=PHP7.0 feature.
Can you create the route `Route::get('/phpinfo', function(){phpinfo();}); and confirm?
`

Comment: I confirmed it & it showed `PHP Version 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186306/discussion-between-cbaconnier-and-khurram-ilyas).